# Setting size for icon in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on JSF, and I'm using this code to display an error box.

```
<div class="pnx-msg pnx-msg-warning clearfix">
    <i class="pnx-msg-icon pnx-icon-msg-warning"/>
</div>
```

The `<i class.../>` part imports a warning icon. It's default size is 36 px, but I need to resize it to 24 px. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `<i style="height: 24px" />` (or maybe `width`)?

Comment: Try font-size: 27px;

Comment: Any Icon is font, so you can use font-size property.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

you can change the size of an icon using the **font size** rather than setting the height and width of an icon. Here is how you do it:

```
<i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" style="font-size: 0.73em;"></i>
```

There are 4 ways to specify the dimensions of the icon.

**px :** give fixed pixels to your icon

**em :** dimensions with respect to your current font. Say ur current font is 12px then 1.5em will     be 18px (12px + 6px).

**pt :** stands for points. Mostly used in print media

**%  :** percentage. Refers to the size of the icon based on its original size.

Comment: this is cool. but what about if you want the icon to have responsive dimensions?

Answer (score 22):

You could override the framework CSS (I guess you're using one) and set the size as you want, like this:

```
.pnx-msg-icon pnx-icon-msg-warning {
    width: 24px !important;
    height: 24px !important;
}
```

The "!important" property will make sure your code has priority to the framework's code.
Make sure you are overriding the correct property, I don't know how the framework is working, this is just an example of !important usage.

Comment: So, how would the code look, exactly? Should I enclose that segment between the <i> tags?

Comment: just add a `<style type="text/css"></style>` section with the contents Diogo specified to your JSF view document (a XHTML doc by the way)

Answer (score 9):

The better way is using 'background-size'.

```
.pnx-msg-icon .pnx-icon-msg-warning{
background-image: url("../pics/edit.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 10px;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

even if your icon dimensions is bigger than 10px it will be 10px.

Answer (score 7):

use the below code in CSS style to customize icon size

```
.pnx-msg i{
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

Comment: Tip : you can use a language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

this works for me try it.

```
height:1rem;
font-size: 3.75em;
```

Answer (score 1):

font-size: 200% !important;
it works for me

Answer (score 0):

None of those work for me.

```css
.fa-volume-down {
    color: white;
    width: 50% !important;
    height: 50% !important;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 7.5%;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-size: 120%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, adjusting the padding seems to do it.

```css
.arrow {
  border: solid rgb(2, 0, 0);
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.first{
  padding: 2vh;
}

.second{
  padding: 4vh;
}

.left {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
```

```html
<i class="arrow first left"></i>
<i class="arrow second left"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to change the size of the icon using just !important. But is there any way to change without using !important. I tried without using this but I somehow couldn't change the size of the icon.