# How do i change an icon property size using CSS?

Tags: html, css, icons, size

i am try to make an icon bigger with `CSS` properties, how do i do this please? i have tried the height and font-size properties, neither work. code below so far:

```
<i class=
"icon2 fa fa-twitter-square">
</i>

.icon2 {
margin:2px 3px 10px 3px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting size for icon in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482249/setting-size-for-icon-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using Font Awesome and actually `font-size` property should work. Anyway, [This documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/) explains a different way. Browse to the **Larger Icons** header and it says:

> To increase icon sizes relative to their container, use the fa-lg (33%
>   increase), fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x classes.

Examples from the documentation:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```